# Public transport to Jotunheimen National Park

Tags: transportation, norway

What are entry points to the Jotunheimen National Park in Norway that I can easily get to with public transport. I plan to land in Oslo in the beginning of September and do some trekking, watching beautiful lakes and mountains of Jotunheimen.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official website](http://www.jotunheimen.com/en/how-to-get-there) it is very easy to get to Lom or Skjåk with 4 daily buses from Oslo.